# "Complete nutrition" in a crockpot?

Tags: nutrition

I recently embarked on an experiment with a product you may have heard of called "Soylent".  The idea appealed to me.  I don't eat as healthy as I should primarily because of the work involved (expense isn't helpful).  I'm a busy young professional and by the time I get home from work, I just don't want to cook.  It's super convenient to pour my dinner from a pitcher that took me 5 minutes or less to prepare the night before and I feel good knowing that I'm getting proper balanced nutrition.

But I just can't do the liquid diet all the time.  It was driving me crazy and I've reverted (mostly) to my old (unhealthy) ways.  It's not that I don't like the taste or anything.  It's actually pretty good after a few days' acclimation.  It's just boring eating (read: "drinking") the same thing all day every day and the lack of solid food seems to present a psychological barrier I wasn't expecting.

While munching on a delicious chicken dish, much like a casserole, that was made for me for my birthday recently, I began to wonder if there was a recipe for some sort of crockpot meal that might offer similar benefits, e.g. total balanced nutrition in a simple-and-inexpensive package.  Something I could dump in the crockpot and come home to perfect food in the evening with little to no effort.  Maybe even make up several days' worth in advance.

Unfortunately, my Googling has turned up nothing but "dieting" recipes.  "Less than 299 calories per serving!" etc.  I'm not interested in "dieting" per se.  Just a simple meal that takes little prep for a reasonable price and contains everything a dietician would like to see me eating.

Does anyone know of such a recipe?  Or multiple such recipes?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Would cooking over the weekend and freezing the dishes, than just thawing and re-heating during the week help? If yes, then you could start with the recipe for that delicious chicken casserole you mentioned?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about health. I also doubt that cooking.SE will take it since they don't welcome recipe requests.

Comment: The internet is full of recipes and meal ideas and making a complete meal in a crockpot with very little effort is perfect for your situation. Start browsing one of the cooking sites like foodnetwork.com and I'm sure you'll see ideas.

Comment: @CareyGregory, respectfully, I believe it has everything to do with health.  But I'm new to this particular SE, so I'll defer to your definition.  Thanks for the tip, too.

Comment: I'm only one vote, so we'll see. If your question had some particular health angel then it would clearly be on topic, but I don't think asking how a healthy young person can cook good meals in a crockpot really qualifies as being about health as defined here http://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Okay.  Probably should have read that first.  I mostly agree with you now, although it seems a bit gray to me.  Thanks again. EDIT: I'd like to point out that when I search for "diet" in the community search, this is the one that comes up.  Maybe that should be addressed?  But yes, per the definitions page, I think this is mostly off topic.